# Getting a response from rest API like {'server1':'ip','server2':'ip'}. How can it be converted in pretty format in go(net/http)

Tags: go

Getting a response from rest API like {'server1':'ip','server2':'ip'}. How can it be converted in pretty format in go(net/http)

```
package main

import(
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "flag"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main(){

    stackPtr:=flag.String("stack","","Stack Name For Getting Instance")
    flag.Parse()
    if  *stackPtr == "" {
        fmt.Println("Argument Is not Provided")
        os.Exit(1)
}
    uri:="http://<ip>:5000/instance/" + *stackPtr
    val, _ := http.Get(uri)
    defer val.Body.Close()
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(val.Body)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",data)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pretty format"? What do you want to accomplish? (also, this will panic on an error -- don't ignore errors)

Comment: pretty json format

Comment: That is json format. Do you just want to rewrite it with newlines and indentation?